# Cannot see any output on console on using onclick property?

Tags: javascript, dom

When I type anything and then click on submit button it doesn't show anything in my console what am I missing.

```
<body>

<form name="fetch-movie-title" id="fetch">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a movie title" id="term" />
     <input type="submit" onclick="showdata()" id="search" value="Find me a poster" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showdata() {
    var film = document.getElementById('term').value;
    console.log(film);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your console log please..

Comment: You're not doing anything to prevent your form from being submitted and reloading the page. Also note that in Chrome you can select the option in the developer tools to preserve the log so that it's not lost between reloads.

Comment: Try making the _Find me a poster_ element a button instead of an element of type submit, since it currently reloads your page after you clicked it.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Ok now works fine thanks please upvote me.

Answer (score 2):

When I run that code I get this error displayed in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

… because you swapped the position of the `</script>` and `</body>` tags.

---

Since you say you see nothing, the problem is most likely because you run the code when the submit button is clicked.

The JS will run then the form will submit and a new page will load.

Unless you configure your console to **Preserve log**, this will clear the console and erase any messages displayed there.

Change the configuration.

[image: Screenshot of console configuration]

Comment: where is preserve console option I cant see it.

Comment: Open the settings (by clicking the cog in the top right corner)

Answer (score 2):

if the body tag is inside the script tag you will be getting a parser error so the function won't be defined when the click happens.

Alternatively, you aren't preventing the form submission so the page might be reloading before you get a chance to see the output.